# Array_key_exists() expects paramete 2 to be array, null given

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

I am getting the error you can see in the title. The code on the page the error is from is here:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
{
    session_start();
}

include "./option.php";

if($start==true)
{
    $ee= md5(microtime());
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
    $_SESSION['new_version']=true;

    if((!isset($_GET['ee']) or !isset($_SESSION['tempLang'])))
    {
        include "./lang/country_code.php";
        function langue($l)
        {
            if(array_key_exists($l, $_GET["lang_con"])) 
            {
                return $_GET["lang_con"][$l];
            } else {
                return "US";
            }
        }
        $lang = substr(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]), 0, 2);
        if ($lang != ''){$con = langue($lang);}else{$con = "US";}
?>
```

And then the supposed null array is in the correct include file and the code is here:

```
$_GET["lang_con"] = array(
    "it" => "IT",
    "ru" => "RU",
    "sv" => "SE",
    "en" => "US",
    "es" => "ES",
    "pl" => "PL",
    "fr" => "FR",
    "no" => "NO",
    "da" => "DK",
    "de" => "DE",
    "nl" => "NL",
    "tr" => "TR",
    "pt" => "BR",
    "zh" => "TW",
    "id" => "US",
    "he" => "IL",
);
```

I really don't know what the problem is.

Please help,

Cheers

Comment: It means `$_GET["lang_con"]` is NOT an array. Why do you assigning value to `$_GET` ?

Comment: @Raptor how would I fix it?

Comment: You should not use php's super globals to define you options.

Comment: Assign the array to it's own variable `$varName = array()`; instead of to the `$_GET` super global.

Answer (score 0):

If the "lang_con" array is defined in the `option.php` or in `lang/country_code.php` include files then your code above should be able to access it. Although, you can add another check on it before using array_key_exists():

```
if (is_array($_GET["lang_con"]) && array_key_exists($l, $_GET["lang_con"])) {
```

However you should **never write** the $_GET superglobal array, **only read** from it. If you need to inject variables into your function, use any other way ([global keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global), [passing as function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php), etc.), but never write $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), as they have a different purpose.